# How to Prevent grouping empty field

Tags: tabulator

i'm using tabulator versione 4.5.2.
I need to group data based on specific field; Normnally i have no problem but if the field is empty the script group alla the matching empty filed in a unmaed group. I need to prevent the creation of this empty group.
[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJqxG.png)
How i can do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The grouping system will group any rows that are present, so your best bet would be to apply a [Filter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/filter) to prevent the rows without a group from being displayed.